# using fastify plugin inside a fastify plugin

Tags: fastify

According the documentation creating a plugin with `fastify-plugin` will not encapsulate and add the plugin content to the "global" fastify scope.

including the dbconnector plugin inside the db plugin doesn't add the inner plugin into the fastify scope.

---

**works**

*server.js*

```
fastify.register(import("./plugins/dbconnector.mjs"));
fastify.register(import("./plugins/db.mjs"), { prefix: "/db" });
```

---

**doesn't**

*server.js*

```
fastify.register(import("./plugins/db.mjs"), { prefix: "/db" });
```

*plugins/db.mjs*:

```
import fastifyPlugin from "fastify-plugin";

async function plugin(fastify, opts) {
     fastify.register(import("./plugins/dbconnector.mjs"));
...
```

---

*dbconnector.mjs* (default documentation example)

```
import fastifyPlugin from "fastify-plugin";

async function dbConnector(fastify, options) {
  fastify.register(import("fastify-mongodb"), {
    url: "mongodb://...",
  });
}
export default fastifyPlugin(dbConnector);
```

Comment: How do you export the `plugins/db.mjs`?

Comment: as fastifyPlugin.

Comment: It should work, I think there could be something with the EJS syntax: are you using webpack? Could you try CJS too?

Comment: changed it to cjs ... still fastify.mongo is undefined in the 2nd solution. https://github.com/inselberg/stackoverflowFastifyPlugin is maybe helpful in order to see what i m missing.

Answer (score 0):

Following this doc [The hitchhiker's guide to plugins](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Guides/Plugins-Guide/)

Fastify starts loading the plugin after `.listen()`, `.inject()` or `.ready()` are called.
so could get value `fastify.mongo?.db?.client?.s?.url` in `example2.js`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Require the framework and instantiate it
const fastify = require("fastify")({
  disableRequestLogging: true, // * https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Server/#disablerequestlogging
  logger: true,
});

fastify.register(require("./plugins/db.js"), { prefix: "/plugin" });

fastify.get("/", async (request, reply) => {
  return { status: "... with plugins" };
});

process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log("UncaughtException processing: %s", err);
});
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
    console.log(fastify.mongo?.db?.client?.s?.url,'load from example2.js after listen')
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
start();
```

In `db.js`:

```
const fastifyPlugin = require("fastify-plugin");

async function dbxxx(fastify, opts) {
  fastify.register(require("./dbconnector.js"));

  console.log(fastify.mongo?.db?.client?.s?.url,'before function in  db.js ')
  fastify.get("/db", async (req, reply) => {
    console.log(fastify.mongo?.db?.client?.s?.url,'inner function in  db.js ')
    const notesCollection = fastify.mongo.db.collection('notes')
    const notes = await notesCollection.find().toArray();
    reply.send(notes);
  });
} // plugin

module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbxxx);
```

When go to browsers and visit http://localhost:3000/db,
could find get the value fastify.mongo